# Is there a way to change the value of all selected "cells" in the MS Access table gui?

Tags: ms-access

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

Is there a way to change the value of all the selected cells in an Access table to one, user specified value ?  In Excel, this would be similar to selecting a set of cells in a column, changing the value of the first, then "Ctrl-Enter" to change the value in all the selected cells.

I was able to do something along these lines using "replace", but that only works if all the values being replaced are the same and the user is willing to click the replace button for every cell they want the replace to work on.  It's a fair solution for this special case.

I can do what I want quite handily using sql.  But the average user of this DB will not know SQL.  Also, I kinda don't want them throwing SQL at the DB if they don't know what they are doing with SQL (so easy to destroy a lot using so little code).

If it's not that simple, I'd like to welcome any brainstorming on how to do this.

Comment: If you're hesitant to let the user run SQL for fear they'll corrupt the data, I'm surprised that you are letting the user open & modify the table data directly...

Comment: Provide that kind of functionality via a form for particular columns.  The form gets a value, then the code behind the form can do the SQL update without having to teach/expose SQL to users.  I can't imagine that you really want users to freely do this for any arbitrary field, as in Excel.  If so, perhaps Excel is a better fit for the users.

Comment: How would the form know which cells the user selected ?

Comment: have the users right click on a given column, and choose a filter. Then they can hit ctrl-f, and then click on replace tab. No code at all. So, you can't really select the columns, but in a database you would filter the form to the criteria you want, and then use ctrl-f to find, or ctrl-f and then click on replace tab.

Comment: I don't think that's going to do what they want.  They don't want to replace a specific string with a different, specific string in the entire column.  They want to replace all values in a column with a specific string but only for the rows they've selected.      I don't know how forms can deal with this unless the form can sense which columns the user has selected.  Is there a way to sense that ?

Comment: Only approach I can envision is user selects fieldname from a combobox, enters replacement text in a textbox, selects records on form, code loops through selected records and saves text to field.